# Validating Hadoop data vs EDW data

Tags: validation, hadoop, testing, db2

I need to compare the data between Qubole (Hadoop data) and EDW data. Since I need to validate billions and billions of data, looking out from you guys to suggest me on any tool or by any other means, by which I can compare these data faster and in an efficient way.

Thank you guys! Your responses are much appreciated.

Thanks, Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar comparison. Bring your non-hadoop data to a hadoop temporary location. Write a short map-reduce program to read both the files, join them and do a column by column comparison. Write out if there are any differences.